# Get the percentile of a column ordered by another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with two columns, `score` and `order_amount`. I want to find the score Y that represents the Xth percentile of `order_amount`. I.e. if I sum up all of the values of `order_amount` where `score <= Y` I will get X% of the total `order_amount`.

I have a solution below that works, but it seems like there should be a more elegant way with `pandas`.

```
import pandas as pd
test_data = {'score': [0.3,0.1,0.2,0.4,0.8],
             'value': [10,100,15,200,150]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(test_data)
df

    score   value
0   0.3 10
1   0.1 100
2   0.2 15
3   0.4 200
4   0.8 150


# Now we can order by `score` and use `cumsum` to calculate what we want 
df_order = df.sort_values('score')
df_order['percentile_value'] = 100*df_order['value'].cumsum()/df_order['value'].sum()
df_order

    score   value   percentile_value
1   0.1 100 21.052632
2   0.2 15  24.210526
0   0.3 10  26.315789
3   0.4 200 68.421053
4   0.8 150 100.000000

# Now can find the first value of score with percentile bigger than 50% (for example)
df_order[df_order['percentile_value']>50]['score'].iloc[0]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Series.searchsorted`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.searchsorted.html):

```
idx = df_order['percentile_value'].searchsorted(50)
print (df_order.iloc[idx, df.columns.get_loc('score')])
0.4
```

Or get first value of filtered Series with `next` and `iter`, if no match returned some default value:

```
s = df_order.loc[df_order['percentile_value'] > 50, 'score']
print (next(iter(s), 'no match'))
0.4
```

One line solution:

```
out = next(iter((df.sort_values('score')
           .assign(percentile_value = lambda x: 100*x['value'].cumsum()/x['value'].sum())
           .query('percentile_value > 50')['score'])),'no matc')
print (out)
0.4
```

Comment: That slightly improves the final step, but I was hoping there might be a one-liner for the 'sort-by-value-cumsum-divide-by-total' part.

Answer (score 2):

here is another way starting from the oriinal dataframe using [`np.percentile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html#numpy.percentile):

```
df = df.sort_values('score')

df.loc[np.searchsorted(df['value'],np.percentile(df['value'].cumsum(),50)),'score']
```

Or [`series.quantile`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.quantile.html)

```
df.loc[np.searchsorted(df['value'],df['value'].cumsum().quantile(0.5)),'score']
```

Or similarly with iloc, if index is not default:

```
df.iloc[np.searchsorted(df['value']
        ,np.percentile(df['value'].cumsum(),50)),df.columns.get_loc('score')]
```

---

```
0.4
```